# UITableView disclosure indicator trailing space

Tags: ios

I am trying to figure out what are the constraints applied to the Disclosure Indicator of a `UITableViewCell`, and specifically the Trailing Space constraint (distance to the right edge)

It sounds to be a 15px constraint on the iPhone 5 and 6 screen, but it is becoming 19 pixel on the iPhone 6+ screen.
I am not so sure to understand what's going on since it should be either 15px on all 3 devices or a different one for all of them.

I have created a dummy project to highlight my issue, the right orange view is 15px width on every device. Here are the screenshots:

[image]

Thank you for helping

Comment: Why do you think it should be the same for all 3, or different for all of them? Apple can choose any default values they think look best, and this is what they chose.

Comment: Because I am assuming they are using some autolayout logic. So either they use some constraint with a fix size, or with a size proportional to the cell width (so screen size in this example). But I assume wrong, so I wonder how they are doing it, hard-code?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the logic, so I can reproduce it, so I can align components outside the table with the ones inside.